# prototype functions like .map does not work in a typescript model

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I fetch data from a server and I defined a typescript model for data which comes from server like this:

```
export class DataModel{
    public PageNo: number
    public showFromDate: string
    public showToDate: string
    public gradeFieldId: number
}

export class ResponseModel<Model>{
    status: number
    message: string
    data: Model
}
```

But in `.then` of `axios` when I want to do some manipulation on my data I got the error `map does not exist on type DataModel`. This error is same for other prototype functions like `.length`.

```
.then(data:ResponseModel<DataModel>)=>{
   data.map(item:any=>{
    ...// some functions
   })
}
```

Now how can I use my model and prototype functions like .map at the same time for this data.

Comment: There is no `.map`. did you mean `<DataModel[]>`?

Comment: `.map` is applicable only to collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the type of `data` property in `ResponseModel` should be an array type.

```ts
export class ResponseModel<Model>{
    status: number
    message: string
    data: Model[]
}
```